# Uploading a File CloudRail Error

Tags: android, cloudrail

I have this code for creating a file, writing inside and uploading it to my dropbox. The file is created correctly, I can't find the solution to the error console. Tried some different solutions involving the call to the path 'context.getFilesDir()', but nothing worked. Does anyone have any idea?

```
File f = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "text2.txt");
    try {

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
        fw.write("Hello, CloudRail");
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("CloudRail", "Error creating temp file", e);

    }

    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(f)) {
        long size = f.length();
        Log.d("CloudRail", "Attempting to upload " + f + " (size: " + size + ")");

        // Make sure the last parameter is true if you need to overwrite files on Dropbox
        //dropbox.createFolder("/TestFolder10");
        dropbox.upload("/TestFolder10", stream, size, true);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("logTAG", "File doesnt exists: " + f.exists());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("CloudRail", "Error uploading file " + f, e);
    }


    return null;
}
```

And the error log:

```
D/CloudRail: Attempting to upload 
/data/user/0/com.example.javier.cloudbymyown/files/text2.txt (size: 16)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.example.javier.cloudbymyown, PID: 705
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while 
executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
                  at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                  at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                  at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at 
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                  at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
               Caused by: com.cloudrail.si.exceptions.HttpException: {"error_summary": "path/conflict/folder/...", "error": {".tag": "path", "reason": {".tag": "conflict", "conflict": {".tag": "folder"}}, "upload_session_id": "AAAAAAAAUjAdvvZEwz47Ew"}}
                  at com.cloudrail.si.services.Dropbox.upload(Dropbox.java:864)
                  at com.example.javier.cloudbymyown.AwesomeAsyncTask.doInBackground(AwesomeAsyncTask.java:94)
                  at com.example.javier.cloudbymyown.AwesomeAsyncTask.doInBackground(AwesomeAsyncTask.java:20)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2605120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa2603230)
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Fixed! I had to specify the path in the upload method: 

    dropbox.upload("/TestFolder10/text2.txt", stream, size, true);